# How can I have two selection in my tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making an app in which `tableViewCells` are expandable, when tapped they expand, I'm doing this by `didSelectRowAt` I also have a check box which responds to tap. But how do I have different selections in the same cell ? I want my check box to animate when tapped on it but also my cell to expand when tapped on the cell area. When tapped on Area 2, I want my cell to expand(which I already have implemented) I also want my Area 1 to receive touch.

[image: Here is what my custom Cell look like]

Here is the code for expanding cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let task = self.tasks[indexPath.row]
let cell=tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }

        var indexPaths : Array<IndexPath> = []
        if let previous = previousIndexPath {
            indexPaths += [previous]
        }
        if let current = selectedIndexPath {
            indexPaths += [current]
        }
        if indexPaths.count > 0 && !task.notes!.isEmpty {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            //tableView.reloadData()

        }

}
```

And gestureRecogniser

```
@IBAction func doneUndone(_ sender: Any) {
    print("tapped")
}
```

Comment: Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your checkbox image.  Don't forget to set `userInteractionEnabled=true` on the image

Comment: I dont think my check box is receiving any touches, maybe my check box is in different class, because I printed a statement in my `UITapGestureRecognizer` and it didnt show up in my console.

Comment: It is a UIImageView?  Make sure you have set its `userInteractionEnabled`.  Show more code

Comment: Where do you add the tap gesture recogniser, if you you are using an open source component, which component?  It probably already has a delegate or even handling method

Comment: @Paulw11 https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMCheckBox this is what I'm using

Comment: You will need to implement the `BEMCheckBoxDelegate` methods in your cell class and then use another protocol to get the event back to your tableview controller if required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139066/discussion-between-s-verma-and-paulw11).